# Destructing optional function parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Scratching my head trying to get this optimal. Say I have a function that takes an object as a parameter and destruct it like so:

```
myfunc = (options = {a:true, b:true, c:true}) => {...}
```

By default a b and c are true. But say I call `myfunc` and want b to be false:

```
myfunc({b:false})
```

well now `options.b === false`, but the values for a and c are gone.
Is there away I can accomplish this without having to pass in a copy of the default values?

I tried something weird like

```
myfunc = (options = Object.assign({a:true, b:true, c:true}, options)) =>{}
```

but that's certainly not right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a default object with a destructuring for the wanted properties with the default value without using `option`. Then create a new one by using short hand properties.

For other objects, you could use, with newer or babeljs, rest properties for objects.

```js
var myfunc = ({ a = true, b = true, c = true, ...rest } = {}) => {
        const option = { a, b, c, ...rest };
        console.log(option);
    };

myfunc();             // take {} as default and the default values inside of the object
myfunc({ b: false }); // take b and default values
myfunc({ foo: 42 });  // take foo and all default values
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is cool, but I need it to be included in a single `option`.
I might end up passing values in that would not be included in the defaults.

Comment: @SpeedOfRound use the ES2018 object rest syntax to include the rest of the values: `{ a = true, b = true, c = true, ...values } = {}`

Comment: Awesome, does exactly what I want. Why does the parameter have to assign to an empty object? I don't understand whats going on here

Comment: you need an object (for the destructuring) if the function is called without value or `undefined`. then you need for the wanted properties other default values to destruct for gettingthe wanted variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass default values inside of destructuring statement:

```
myFunc = ({a=true, b=true, c=true})
```

Downside obviously is inability to refer to the options as a whole.
So maybe having `options` as a parameter and making destructuring in function body is better option:

```
myfunc = (options={}) => {
    const {a=true, b=true, c=true} = options;
    ....
}
```